# Character encoding in ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, nokogiri

I am parsing some data from one Holland site using Nokogiri, and saving data into csv. But data are not correctly displayed. For example on form thre is Einddatum1 empty space but when I print it into console before saving it is showed as "\u00A0". Also other strings are not correctly displayed, for example "Univ\u00E9 Zorg Geregeld Polis".

```
{:Bsn=>"112511111",
 :Verzekerde=>"VerzekerdeAHM Andes-Faasse",
 :Pakketnaam1=>"Univ\u00E9 Zorg Geregeld Polis",
 :Verzekerdennummer1=>"1234987654",
 :Begindatum1=>"01 jan 2012",
 :Einddatum1=>"\u00A0",
 }
```

Maybe header of this html page could be relevant:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head id="Head1"><meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet)
         Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><title>
    Verzekeringsrecht controleren
</title><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="nl-NL" />
```

It seams like it's utf-8 but there is problem with these characters. How to properly encode them?

Comment: You have to set the external encoding to UTF-8. I don't know how to do that with Nokogiri, but I'm sure you can.

Comment: I set encoding in while creating Nokogiri but nothing changes. Maybe it's not UTF-8?

Comment: To me that looks like what it's supposed to look like. The \u00A0 btw is a &nbsp; in the markup. You can just gsub them out of there with: str.gsub(/\u00A0/,'')

Comment: Sure I can, but there are few other characters like `\u00E9`. I thought it could be converted with some method.

Comment: \u00E9 is a legitimate unicode char. You don't want to change that.

Comment: Why it's not blank space like on web page? Is there some gem that converts it into real representation. I save it in csv and after I open that csv it is recognized like some strange chars, not like blank space.

Comment: It's not blank space, it's an e with an accent.

Comment: How do you know this? Is there some table where I can look and manually (with gsub) replace characters in my script?

Answer (score 1):

Then the line would read `:Pakketnaam1=>"Univé Zorg Geregeld Polis",`

Is that what is supposed to be there and your console encoding is just not defined so Ruby does not know how to display the Unicode characters when printing them or should there be some more text?

Comment: This is exactly what there should be. It's not problem about console, but after saving it to csv it's not saved on proper way.

Comment: @ИванБишевац the CSV might be written correctly. Make sure you open it with UTF-8 encoding.